# Working with multiple forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I would like to load multiple forms within a form using user controls and I've tried the following code but nothing seems to happen after clicking on button1. Anyone knows what's wrong?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 control = new UserControl1();
        control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(control);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Are there other controls on your form1?

Comment: Make sure the button's click event was wired up to run that code when clicked.

Comment: Are there other controls on your UserControl1 or is it just an empty control?

Comment: It seems to be working now, however the contents of UserControl1 seems to be overlapping and I can still see the content of Form1, any idea why is this happening?

Comment: @Hans there is only a label on UserControl1

Comment: Have you set the properties for the UserControl1, size etc?

Comment: @CodeBlend Yup i have set to the exact size

Comment: You are using dock fill on the usercontrol, so the size you set will not matter. How are the other controls position on your form? Screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however the contents of UserControl1 seems to be overlapping and I can still see the content of Form1

The Z-order of the controls on the form matters.  With Controls.Add(), the control ends up on the bottom of the order, existing controls overlap it.  You fix it like this:

```
    this.Controls.Add(control);
    control.BringToFront();
```

Or use Controls.SetChildIndex() to insert it between controls.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change the value of `Dock` property. When it is `DockStyle.Fill` -- it will just take the whole area. Try to change it to other value, depending what layout you need.